# Reinstalling Ubuntu on a partitioned hard drive

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, reinstall, ubuntu-14.04, boot-partition

I had Win7 installed on my laptop, then created a partition and installed Ubuntu on it so I can dual boot. However, being pretty new to Ubuntu I have messed around too much and would simply like to reinstall Ubuntu (I still have the .iso on a DVD). I don't care about backing up anything have on it. Is it a risk-free process just restarting with the DVD in and reinstalling from there?

I've haven't found a tutorial for this anywhere online, but I have found stories of people with Windows 8 (partitioned with Ubuntu) trying this and wiping out Windows.

By the way, if you can suggest a better way of getting back to a fresh installation of Ubuntu without reinstalling from the disk, I'd be happy to that too, but again, I couldn't find any way of doing that from searching the forums.

Thanks.

Comment: This should help you on reinstalling Ubuntu in a proper way, so that you dont loose your Windows Data. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Answer (score 0):

My solution was:

1. Boot into Windows 7
2. Navigate to Disk Management in System
3. Right click and remove the old Ubuntu partition(s) that you don't want any more (I made just one to install Ubuntu, but that had some how become 2). 
   You might have to right click again and delete, until there is a partition left labelled 'Unallocated'.
4. Now you can restart and install Ubuntu from the DVD as you did the first time.

Done. It worked just fine.